# Cannot create shared texture in D3D9 from D3D11 when using dedicated GPU

Tags: directx, interop, directx-11, directx-9

I'm working on an interop between DirectX 11 and DirectX 9 where I'm first creating a D3D11 Texture, get the shared DXGI handle and then create a D3D9 texture using the handle. For device creation I use the default adapter for DX11 and DX9.

As long as I have "Auto-Select" or "Integrated graphics" set as the preferred graphics processor in the NVIDIA Control Panel it works fine, but when I choose the high performance option it fails. The device creation also works fine in this case and my dedicated GPU is selected as expected.

The error I get is "Value does not fall within the expected range", when calling CreateTexture on my IDirect3DDevice9Ex. Does texture sharing like this work on the GPU or do I miss something in my configuration of the resources?

I'm using the Silk.NET wrapper for DirectX. Here are my snippets for the texture creation

First for the D3D11 texture:

```cs
var texture2DDesc = new Texture2DDesc()
{
    BindFlags       = (uint)(BindFlag.RenderTarget),
    Format          = Silk.NET.DXGI.Format.FormatB8G8R8A8Unorm,
    Width           = width,
    Height          = height,
    MipLevels       = 1,
    SampleDesc      = new SampleDesc(1, 0),
    Usage           = Usage.Default,
    MiscFlags       = (uint)ResourceMiscFlag.None,
    CPUAccessFlags  = 0, 
    ArraySize       = 1
};
```

Then getting the shared handle from IDXGIResource interface via GetSharedHandle and using it to create the D3D9 texture:

```cs
d3D9ExDevice.CreateTexture(
                Width:          width,
                Height:         height,
                Levels:         1,
                Usage:          D3D9.UsageRendertarget,
                Format:         Silk.NET.Direct3D9.Format.A8R8G8B8, 
                Pool:           Pool.Default, 
                ppTexture:      ref d3D9Texture,
                pSharedHandle:  &sharedHandle
            );
```

This function fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem:

There was a flag missing in Texture2DDesc and if you set the following it works.

```
BindFlags = (uint)(BindFlag.RenderTarget | BindFlag.ShaderResource)
```